# How to set properties in a custom HttpMessageHandler?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient

I am developing a cross-platform Xamarin Forms app, and I want to be able to use the platform-specific `HttpMessageHandler` subclasses `AndroidClientHandler` and `NSUrlSessionHandler` respectively, when I initialize the `HttpClient` object.

To accomplish this, I am configuring the Android and iOS app projects to use native HTTP client implementations, and then I use the parameterless constructor to initialize `HttpClient`:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
```

However, I also would like to ensure that `AllowAutoRedirect` and `UseCookies` of the message handler are set to `false`. There is no `Handler` property in the `HttpClient` class. How can I ensure that these handler properties are correctly set in the implicitly initialized handler objects?

Since this is cross-platform code, I would like to avoid as much as possible to resort to using the `HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler)` constructor and explicitly pass in platform-specific handler instances. If at all possible, I would like to be able to pre-configure the properties of the handlers that are initialized in the parameterless constructor.

**EDIT**

From API documentation, it is easy to get the impression that the platform-specific handler implementations will be applied if you pass a `HttpClientHandler` object to the `HttpClient` constructor:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
  AllowAutoRedirect = false,
  UseCookies = false
};
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

**Unfortunately, the above does not work in practice.** With this approach, a `HttpClientHandler` object will be instantiated, regardless of whether `HttpClient` implementation has been set to native in the project settings.

In theory, one alternative would be if there was any way to obtain an instance of the handler that is initialized in the parameterless constructor, modify it and pass the modified instance into the `HttpMessageHandler` argument constructor, something like this:

```
var handler = GetHandlerInstanceAppliedInParameterlessHttpClientConstructor();
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
handler.UseCookies = false;
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

However, I am not aware of any method returning such a handler instance.

I should also point out that my main concern right now is Android, so an answer that applies primarily to Android might be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to expose the native handlers and implement it for both platforms. `HttpClient` accepts an overload with a handler, like you stated. However, that handler is a **.NET Standard** handler. So, if you initialise the handler in the shared project, or inherit from it in the native ones, they are the same type of class.

In your shared project, you can simply initialise the client like this:

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    UseCookies = false
};
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

However, this way you will override the "native" handler and will use HttpClientHandler instead.

Additional remarks, based on comments and edited question:

To answer your question - no, there isn'y any built-in way to get the `AndroidClientHandler` in the shared code. You'll have to expose it yourself. You can also write your own native handlers and expose them through a `DependencyService` and then invoke the ctor with them. The latter I have done in the past and it worked with no issues.

Comment: Well, my experience is that this is **not** what happens using the `HttpMessageHandler` argument constructor. When debugging the Android app, I see that when I use your approach, the _handler instance is of type `HttpClientHandler`, whereas if I use the parameterless constructor, the _handler instance is of type `AndroidCleintHandler`.

Comment: Yes, but `AndroidClientHandler` inherits from `System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.android.net.androidclienthandler?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: And the behavior is different too. With the parameterless constructor, I do not get a crash, whereas when using `HttpClient(handler)` I *do* get a crash (given the specific scenario I am currently debugging). So no, using the approach you are suggesting does not seem to be the way forward.

Comment: Yes, `AndroidClientHandler` inherits from `HttpClientHandler` but the instance in the debugging mode should still be visible as an `AndroidClientHandler` if this was what had actually been instantiated.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the initial confusion. I see your point now. I do not use shared projects for this, so your proposal is not an immediate solution for me, but in principle it should work (I guess). I will examine further.

Comment: I have now double-checked: if I add this line directly in the Android app code: `var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());`, the `_handler` instance is of type `HttpClientHandler`. If I instead use the parameterless constructor, `var client = new HttpClient();`, the `_handler` instance is of type `AndroidClientHandler`. So, unfortunately, your assumption regarding the `HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler)` constructor does appear to be wrong.

Comment: What do you mean that you are not using shared code? Aren't you working with Xamarin.Forms? Also, take a look at HttpClient's implementation (if you are using .NETStandard project). You can see that whether or not you use the empty ctor, or a handler, the logic behind is the same.
https://imgur.com/a/fJWgWhx

Comment: With shared code I thought you meant "shared library" as opposed to "compiled library". But regardless, it does not work as you suppose. Please check for yourself, you just need to apply the example code I provided in the comment above.

Comment: Of course that it won't work if you add it in Android. I thought that the whole idea of your post is to avoid having it done for each system. If you add the handler in the shared project (whatever you have - PCL, share library, etc), then it will plug itself and will use the native implementation, overriding the properties that you want.

Comment: Yes, I have read your comments and nowhere are you stating that you have tried this. As per your previous comments you are replacing the handler in the ANDROID project, which is not what I have said at no time. Of course, if you explicitly say that you want that type of handler, it will override it. I tried replacing it in the SHARED project, and it works as expected (you can triple check, when you see the source code also). Regarding a method that will return the handler - there isn't one, you will have to expose one yourself, but beware of the handler type, since they are all native types.

Comment: Have you really checked the type of the `HttpClient._handler` object in the debugger?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. After reading carefully through your comments, I get what you are trying to achieve. To answer your question again - no, there isn'y any built-in way to get the `AndroidClientHandler` in the shared code. Like I said, you have to expose it yourself. You can also write your own native handlers and expose them through a `DependencyService` and then invoke the ctor with them. The latter I have done in the past and it worked with no issues.

Comment: Right. I have recently tried all the approaches you are suggesting. I would have hoped that there was some shortcut, since the way it needs to be handled right now does not seem fully thought through. I have asked a similar question on the documentation page for custom HTTP client handlers in Xamarin Android, hopefully someone at least recognizes these shortcomings.

Comment: Please consider to edit your answer also, since what you are currently stating is not correct.